# Access ODBC Subform field size too small to edit

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I have a form with a combo box that allows a user to filter data in a subform using

> DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[Division] = " & "'" & Screen.ActiveControl & "'"

The user should then add data to the subform below.

I've two problems:

1. When the user tries to edit this data, they get "The field is too
   small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try
   inserting or pasting less data". It doesn't matter which of the
   fields the user tries to enter data into, they all suffer this
   problem.
2. The "Division" field that has been filtered, shows up as #Error for
   the new record line. I've set a temp variable for this (see below), so it should
   be showing the value used for the filter, but does so with or without the default set.

   > TempVars.add "Div", [Combo5].Value

I've looked in my ODBC forms and all the data types/sizes etc look to be the same.

There's data already in this form, which can be edited, even though it's the same size, but no new records can be saved. As well as this I can edit data in the supporting table.

Comment: Are any of the columns in your table defined as 'Memo'? What size are your columns defined as? IS there any filter on the subform before the user selects a value from the combobox?

Comment: SearchForRecord does not filter, it searches.
The fact that you are trying to search a subform and not supplying the first two parameters, is probably confusing Access.
I would suggest using the Find method on the subform's recordsetclone object and then setting the bookmark.
Also debug.print your 'Find' criteria to make sure it contains what you expect.

Comment: @AVG Can I use recordsetclone when I want to edit the data? I thought it was read only?

Comment: Yes, it is editable. A simple bingoogle search will provide you with a wealth of information. Here is one sample that contains exactly what you are trying to achieve. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa173229(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @AVG Thanks for the tip. You're right - after further research the search function was causing the errors. However, I'm seriously struggling with the recordsetclone / bookmark. I think it's because my subform is actually a datasheet, so whilst the bookmark is set to the first desired record, it's still showing all of the records in the list and is not limiting to this filter. 

Is there anyway to filter the datasheet in a subform?

Comment: Your form/subform has a property 'Filter'. Set that as needed (i.e. MyBlnFld = false). Either set via code (Me.Filter = "MyBlnFld = false": Me.FilterOn = True) or at design time.

Comment: Find is not filter. It is find. If you want to filter, then filter.
Me!<yoursubform>.Form.Filter = <yourfilter>.
Me!<yoursoubform>.Form.FilterOn= True

Answer (score 0):

Answer

Thanks to @AVG and @WayneG.Dunn for help. I ended up using the following code and using the filter as suggested. I couldn't get it to work very well on the subform, so I hid the field and used that as a Master Field for the subform. Still getting and error message "field too small" and "#ERROR" in the new record label, but the form works, so I'm just going to use it as is. Code for reference:

> DoCmd.SetFilter "Division", "Division = " & "'" & [Combo5].Value & "'"